# Apt-get says up to date, errors say no update log?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, crash

I am on a relatively fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, but I have updated and upgraded with apt-get multiple times. The Software Updater confirms that I everything is up to date. But I frequently have various applications crashing,  and in the crash report dialog windows it says that there is no update log on my system and that I am probably on a fresh install. It this common? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: It is not a problem, lack of an update log means you installed 14.04 as opposed to installing a previous version (say 12.04) and then updating to 14.04.

Comment: @bain That helps! If you want to add that comment as an answer, I will accept it. The stuff crashing *is* still a problem, but at least I know this has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem, lack of an update log means you installed 14.04 as opposed to installing a previous version (say 12.04) and then updating to 14.04.